# C# if certain text selected in combobox winform

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, combobox

i have 3 combobox : cmbStatus,cmbReason,cmbTransfer, primarykey textbox txtNo_RM and the trigger button: btnAdd. Using Mysql as Database

While cmbStatus != "Transfered" cmbReason and cmbTransfer will be intended to not be selected by user. The problem is it didn't work while i use this code

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    con.Open();
    try
    {
        cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into tb_data(No_RM,Status,Reason,Transfer)Values(@No_RM,@Status,@Reason,@Transfer)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NO_RM", txtNo_Rm.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", cmbStatus.Text);

        if (cmbStatus.Text == "Transfered")
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", cmbReason.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transfer", cmbTransfer.Text);
        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    }
    finally
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
            LoadData();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Added!");
        }
    }



}
```

code above resulting fatal error message and also using SelectedText.ToString

try adding this code, resulting out of range error

```
if (cmbStatus.Text != "Transfered")
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", "");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transfer", "");
            }
```

thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DBValue.Null` for empty values like this:

```
if (cmbStatus.Text == "Transfered")
{
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", cmbReason.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transfer", cmbTransfer.Text);
}
else
{
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", DBNull.Value);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transfer", DBNull.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the property `SelectedValue` for comboboxes instead of `Text`. Also assign `DBNull.Value` or default value to the parameters `@Reason` and `@Transfer` if the cmbStatus.Text != "Transfered".

Comment: while changing the property to SelectedValue also works, after stop debugging i get a warning: Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'

Answer (score 0):

Consider the parameterized query that you are using, it expecting four parameters as you specified in the query So you should five the four otherwise you will get that error as you described in the question; What you can do in this situation is :

```
cmd = con.CreateCommand();
if (cmbStatus.Text == "Transfered")
{
    cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into tb_data(No_RM,Status,Reason,Transfer)Values(@No_RM,@Status,@Reason,@Transfer)";      
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", cmbReason.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transfer", cmbTransfer.Text);
}
else
{
    cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into tb_data(No_RM,Status)Values(@No_RM,@Status)";         
}
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NO_RM", txtNo_Rm.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", cmbStatus.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: while i want to try this code, below provide a simple answer. but anyway thanks for answering